# My scrollbar doesn't work - tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Well, I'm adding many buttons to my Canvas called "itemsFrame" in order to test the ScrollBar, but it doesn't work

Well, I haven't tried much because I don't know about the subject, I've investigated how to do it but it only comes out with small buttons without being able to resize them

```
from tkinter import Frame, Label, Button, Entry, messagebox, ttk, Scrollbar, Canvas

import base64
import json

class WatchNewsFrame(Frame):
    name = "WatchNewsFrame"

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.Parent = parent
        self.initializecomponents()
        pass

    def set_news(self):
        data = json.load(open(self.file))["News"]
        cont = 1
        for key in range(10):
            Panel = Button(self.itemsFrame)
            Panel.config(bg="#656565", activebackground="#808080")
            Panel.place(relwidth=.95, relheight=0.245, rely=.028+key*0.25, relx=.5, anchor="n")
        pass

    def initializecomponents(self):
        Frame.__init__(self, self.Parent)

        self.itemsFrame = Canvas(self)
        self.ItemsScrooll = Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")

        # this frame
        self.config(background=self.Parent["background"])
        self.place(relwidth=0.95, relheight=0.95, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

        # ItemsScrooll
        self.ItemsScrooll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # itemsFrame
        self.itemsFrame.config(bg="#606060", highlightbackground="#FFFFFF", yscrollcommand=self.ItemsScrooll.set)
        self.itemsFrame.place(relheight=0.85, relwidth=0.9, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        self.itemsFrame.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mouse_wheel)

        self.ItemsScrooll.config(command=self.itemsFrame.yview)

        # events
        self.set_news()
        pass
    pass
```

Comment: First, you don't need to call `Frame.__init__(self, self.Parent)` inside `initializecomponents()`.  Second, putting buttons into canvas using `.place()` will not affect the final bounding box of all items in the canvas because those buttons are not canvas items.  You need to use `self.itemsFrame.create_window()` to put those buttons into the canvas instead.  Final, you have never updated the `scrollregion` of the canvas.  May be it is updated inside `resize_text()` but this function definition is not included in posted code.

Comment: Well I already tried that but now the buttons just don't fill the frame inside the canvas because it won't let me resize the buttons

Comment: You can specify the width and height options when creating the buttons.

Comment: that's right, but it's "width" and "height" don't resize when resizing the window, others like "relheight" and "relwidth" would, but it won't let me do it.